# I haven't filed taxes since 2012, unable to work so no income, married but husband deserted me early 2013, do I qualify for a stimulus payment?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, marriage, stimulus, disability

I haven't filed taxes since 2012 (married, filling jointly at that time). I've been unable to work since 2007, medical issues, but can't qualify for SSD/SSI and I haven't had medical insurance since around 2008. 
I'm married, but my husband deserted me April 2013 and hasn't contributed financially since mid 2013. I don't know what status he uses when he files his taxes. (married filling separately or?) I have no way of contacting him to ask.
My father, Retired Army 1st SGT, has been paying my rent since 2013. I've been going to food banks and using SNAP benefits, when I can qualify for them, since 2013.
Would I qualify for a stimulus payment? If not, could my father qualify for a larger stimulus payment since he supports me by paying my rent? I'm lucky enough to have electric included in my rent.

Comment: Does your father pay more than 50% of your living expenses?

Comment: Yes. Other than food, rent is my only expense and he pays the entire amount every month since 08/2013.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately it sounds like you won't be getting anything, even if you file a return with no income.

You said in a comment that your father pays more than 50% of your living expenses. This means he can [claim you as a dependent](https://www.thebalance.com/claiming-adult-dependent-tax-rules-4129176), which means you are ineligible for the stimulus check. Note that even if he does not claim you, you still can't get the check. The questions is *could* he claim you as a dependent, regardless of whether he does or not.

Your father would also not get the extra $500 for you since I assume you are over 16 years old.

Comment: I am, turned 50 last November. If he can't get the $500 stimulus, could be claim me as a dependent relative? If so, what kind/type of deductions would he possibly qualify for?

Comment: @TexasBlueEyes: see the link. Starting with 2018, he can take the _credit_ for other dependents, $500 (for one person). This credit is nonrefundable, so he only gets the full benefit of it if he had/has at least that much tax liability (before the credit).

Comment: @TexasBlueEyes dave_thompson is correct, he would still get a tax credit for claiming you as a dependent.